# SQL xml output parameter throwing error?

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2008, coldfusion

I have a SQL Server stored procedure that has an output param of type `xml`. In my coldfusion code, I'm not sure which `cfsqltype` to use for an xml variable. I tried using a `cf_sql_varchar` in the following code:

```
<cfprocparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" type="out" variable="result">
```

But I get the following error:

> Implicit conversion from data type xml to varchar is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.

Is there any way to deal with the xml output param in coldfusion without having to change the stored procedure to return a varchar instead of xml?

Comment: you should be able to use `cf_sql_longvarchar` I've never understood why `cf_sql_varchar` doesn't work

Comment: @MattBusche - `cf_sql_varchar` is for smaller strings. The xml type is more similar to  `text` or `varchar(max)`, in terms of capacity (and how it is stored), so that is why it maps to `cf_sql_longvarchar`.

Comment: Just took a closer look w/CF9 and can see it works for `in` parameters but not `out`. I know JDBC 4 supports the SQLXML type, but it does not look like there support for it in CF. *None* of the cfsqltypes worked. The only way it worked was using cfquery ie `<cfquery ...>DECLARE @xml xml EXEC procedureName @xml OUTPUT SELECT @xml AS Result</cfquery>`, which is a bit kludgey imo.  But that is the only option I can think of other than casting the result as a varchar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the answer to your question is no. The driver does not support reading stored procedure output of the XML data type. If you have to use the XML data type as an output parameter, you must first convert the XML data type to a VARCHAR or LONGVARCHAR in the stored procedure before it can be read.

Comment: Yeah, that seemed to be the general consensus based on their original results and my later tests. Have you seen any official documentation to that effect or is that just an observation?

Comment: At adobe.com docs for CF https://learn.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/cfqueryparam , the table with mapping of ColdFusion SQL data types with JDBC SQL types, you can see XML is not there.

Comment: Yep, I am aware of the query param matrix. But from my tests it obviously can interact with xml - somewhat (ie as strings). Otherwise, my cfquery example above would not work either. I was just hoping there was something more definitive, like a statement about what level JDBC the drivers support: 2, 3 or 4. The only thing I can find in the docs is that it is a type 4 driver (Duh! These days everything is type 4 other than the one for Access).

Comment: Never mind, tired eyes. [The drivers are compliant with JDBC 2.2](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7d52.html). (BTW, I have frequently found sections of the documentation that are out of date or incomplete, so ... I tend not to take it as gospel ;-).